# The meaning of "to make it on their own so young"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of the bolded expression in the following sentences?

> Professor: Now when they emerge in the spring from hibernation,
>   the mating process begins. For them, well, they come together to mate
>   and then they go their separate ways. Then about six to eight weeks
>   after birth, the offspring leave their mothers. Student: Really? Just
>   six weeks? Is that possible for the offspring **to make it on their own
>   so young**?

Comment: Did you look up these words? They have their normal meanings: to survive, without parental aid, at such a young age.

Comment: @Davo You're right. I couldn't see "make it" in the dictionary. Please make an answer that I accept it.

Comment: I think we can understand **so young** as a sort of subjectless verbless nonfinite adverbial clause with the subject understood to be "offspring": *[they|them being] so young*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo you mean "so young" is an equivalent of "when they are so young"?

Comment: No, not "when they are so young" but "they being so young", that is, "inasmuch as they are so young". It expresses the basis for the question "is that possible?"  If that is what you meant by **when**, then, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These words use standard meanings, but perhaps the phrasing was misleading:

> Is that possible for the offspring to make it **(to survive)** on their own **(without parental aid)** so young **(at such a young age)**?

Comment: Thank you. Please give some explanation on "so young" language structure.

Comment: "So" is used as per definition one at https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/so Why do you drive your car so fast? Why do you eat so much? Why do you ask so many questions?

Comment: I paraphrased it but I still have a problem with it: "... to survive without any help so young.".

Comment: Read it as an elision: ...to survive on their own (at) so young (an age).

Comment: In that case is OK. But I want to know how that such a conversion can occur?

Comment: That is out of the scope of this question, I'm afraid.